# Suggestions for alternative 3D space partition tessellation, different from Voronoi and Delaunay

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a system of mono-disperse spheres inside a cubic box. I am studying the volume distribution inside the sample, after tessellating it with either Voronoi and Delaunay tessellations. I am interested on some properties which should not depend on the tessellation.

Currently, I am comparing with the values obtained from Voronoi and Delaunay. I would like to know if you are familiar with another space partition approach (It is important that the final sum of the individual cells add up to the total volume, and the cells should be disjoint). Furthermore, in case you know another kind of tessellation, do you also know a library which already implements it, preferable in C/C++ or python?

Some variations, like Laguerre partitions, coincide with my current Voronoi approach since the spheres are mono-disperse. Another candidate will be the Centroidal Voronoi tessellation, although I have not found yet a library to do that (although it could lead to evenly spaced cells which does not reflect the disorder inside the system, which is not desirable).

For a given tessellation, the spheres' centers are used to perform the tessellation. In the case of Voronoi, each cell wil enclose the sphere.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

NOTE: I have asked this at stackoverflow. I was suggested to ask here, but I do not have enough points to migrate a question. The original question link is : https://stackoverflow.com/q/16598913/505047

Comment: iluvatar, you don't need points to migrate your question.  Just click the "flag" button underneath your StackOverflow post, indicate that this needs moderator attention, select "Other" to provide a custom reason, and ask the moderators to migrate the question.  Except... now that you've asked it twice, I suggest you flag your post on StackOverflow and ask the moderator to close it or merge it with this one, so we don't have duplicates.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks a lot. I have just made the petition. Many people were upset after my mistake. Hope I get some answer ...